# QSettings instance fails

Tags: c++, qt, settings

I was wondering why this code to create a Qt settings instance based on a fake company name and application name, isn't working.

Here is the mainwindow.h, there is also a main.cpp, and mainwindow.cpp, a .pro file, .ui file, but they are all completely generic, as I made a new qwidgets project to see exactly what the problem was.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSettings>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QSettings these_settings("MySoft","StarRunner");
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

All I did was add the one line of code, `QSettings these_settings("MySoft","StarRunner");`.

This page, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings, shows the instance type I am trying to create.

The error is:

> expected identifier before string constant, ',' or '...'.

Comment: QSettings these_settings = QSettings("MySoft","StarRunner"); results in a message about 'macro Q_DISABLE_COPY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enabled C++11? This is needed if you what initialized field like this.
Also this should be done with braces not parenthesis:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QSettings these_settings { "MySoft","StarRunner" };

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure about the braces? On the link it shows parenthesis. But I'll try ur suggestion

Comment: with parenthesis compiler thinks that this is definition of method that is why it complains.

Comment: You could have used parenthesis in the constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

file:///home/rajendra/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: Failed to initialize QSettings instance. Status code is: 1

file:///home/rajendra/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:102:33: QML Settings: The following application identifiers have not been set: QVector("organizationName", "organizationDomain")

like this error i have.

Add below in your main.cpp

**QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Some organization");**

It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).